# Where to Add Authentication Header?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I have PHP files that are awaiting a webhook POST from my wordpress website. Both sites have HTTPS and im getting 401 errors from WooCommerce.

test_updated_webhook.txt:

```
<pre>stdClass Object
(
    [code] => woocommerce_rest_cannot_view
    [message] => Sorry, you cannot view this resource.
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 401
        )

)
</pre>
```

I have set API keys and now im not too sure on where to add Authentication Headers to my code being that Its awaiting POST data. I'm not too sure on where it should be added.
PHP:

```
<?php
 session_start();
   include "../db_conn.php";
   include "../config.php";
   include "../functions.php";

if($json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))) {
  $order = $json;
  file_put_contents("request_confirm.txt","request arrived");

  //https://woocommerce.com/document/managing-orders/
  if($order->status == "completed")
  {
    $purchased_hours=0;
    //get all line items and store total purchased hours in database.
    foreach ($order->line_items  as $line_item)
    {
      if($line_item->sku != "")
      {
        //sku is the number of hours in the package (e.g. 5 hours) and quantity mean how many of the package
        $hours=$line_item->sku * $line_item->quantity;
        $purchased_hours+=$hours;
      }
      else
      {
        //quantity is total number of hours purchased
        $purchased_hours+=$line_item->quantity;
      }
    }
    $purchased_at=$order->date_created;
    $user=$order->billing->first_name." ".$order->billing->last_name;
    $order_id=$order->id;

    $data="Purchased_hours: ".$purchased_hours." Cutomer name: ".$user." purchased_at: ".$purchased_at;
    $purchased_seconds=$purchased_hours*3600;
//    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_hours (purchased_seconds, name, purchased_at) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    try{
      $sql = "INSERT INTO user_hours (purchased_seconds, name, purchased_at, order_id) SELECT ".
        "?,?,?,? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_hours".
        " WHERE order_id = '$order_id')";
      $insert= $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $insert->execute([$purchased_seconds, $user, $purchased_at, $order_id]);
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
      file_put_contents("error.txt",$exception." order number: ".$order->id);
    }

  }
  $txt = "<pre>".print_r($order, true)."</pre>";
  file_put_contents("test_webhook.txt",$txt);
  file_put_contents("test_webhook_collected_data.txt",$data);
  return;

} else {
  print_r($_POST);
    $data = $_POST;
  $txt = "<pre>".print_r($data, true)."</pre>";
  file_put_contents("test_form.txt",$txt);
  return;
}

   ?>
```

Comment: Side note: You are using prepared statements with your query, which is great, but you're still concatenating the `$order_id` in the `WHERE` clause. You should replace the last `'$order_id'` also with a `?` and then add a second `$order_id` to the array you are passing to `$insert->execute`.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks! Ill add those changes